# ForeignKey en Tablas c# mvcrazor

Tags: c#, sql-server, mvc, razor

que tal amigo buenas noches, les presento al siguiente situación y espero puedan ayudarme.

1.- resulta que tengo 2 entidades (ejemplos)

```
public class Tabla1
{

    [Key]
    public int Tabla1Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Nombre ")]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("GenericId")]
    public virtual ICollection<MtoAdjunto> MtoAdjuntos { get; set; }
}



public class Tabla2
{

    [Key]
    public int Tabla2Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Nombre ")]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("GenericId")]
    public virtual ICollection<MtoAdjunto> MtoAdjuntos { get; set; }
}
```

y cada una debe poder adjuntar archivos, por lo que hice una tabla para adjuntos.

```
 public class MtoAdjunto
{

    public MtoAdjunto() {
        GenericId = 0;

    }

        [Key]
        public int MtoAdjuntoId { get; set; }


        public int? GenericId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Nombre Documento")]
        public string NombreArchivo { get; set; }


        [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
        [Display(Name = "Subir Archivo")]
       //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Por favor elija el archivo para cargar.")]
        public string Ruta { get; set; }

    //relacion con la tabla de licitacion        
    public virtual Tabla1 MtoProcedimientos { get; set; }
    public virtual Tabla2 MtoRequerimientos { get; set; }

}
```

Ahora bien para cuando intento guardar un registro de la tabla 1 me manda el siguiente mensaje

```
SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.MtoAdjunto_dbo.Tabla1_GenericId". The conflict occurred in database "WebDBT", table "dbo.tabla1", column 'tabla1Id'.
```

The statement has been terminated.

entiendo que se tiene que repetir los GenericId, es aquí donde solicito su ayuda es necesario hacer una tabla de adjuntos por cada tabla que necesite adjuntos o puedo en una tabla de adjuntos englobar todos los documentos pensando que cada tabla tiene su key única y que se pueden repetir.

de antemano muchas gracias por su apoyo.

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en la relación que estas definiendo, te flata las llaves foráneas de tabla1 y tabla2 en la tabla MtoAdjunto. debería quedarte de esta manera:

```
    public class MtoAdjunto
{

    public MtoAdjunto() {
        GenericId = 0;

    }

        [Key]
        public int MtoAdjuntoId { get; set; }


        public int? GenericId { get; set; }

        public int Tabla1Id { get; set; }//llave extranjera de la tabla1

        public int Tabla2Id { get; set; }//llave extranjera de la tabla2

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Nombre Documento")]
        public string NombreArchivo { get; set; }


        [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
        [Display(Name = "Subir Archivo")]
       //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Por favor elija el archivo para cargar.")]
        public string Ruta { get; set; }

    //relacion con la tabla de licitacion        
    public virtual Tabla1 MtoProcedimientos { get; set; }
    public virtual Tabla2 MtoRequerimientos { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: que tal amigo si, entiendo pero imaginate si son 15 tablas las que tiene que relacionar con esta, por eso crei que seria bueno, que todo sea en una sola tabla por eso el GenericId pero bueno mientras creo que tendre que crear tabla de adjuntos por cada tabla maestro